# Elastic Beanstalk Config fails when trying to install GhostScript 9.10

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ghostscript, ebextensions

I'm trying to install GhostScript 9.10 on Elastic Beanstalk because currently only Ghostscript 8.70 is available via yum packages.

The installation is working via SSH on the EC2 instance but the configuration file is always failing and I don't understand whats the reason.

Here is my .ebextensions configuration file:

```
commands:
    01_admin_rights:
        command: "sudo su"
    02_get_gs:
        command: "curl -O http://downloads.ghostscript.com/public/old-gs-releases/ghostscript-9.10.tar.gz"
    03_extract_gs:
        command: "tar -xzf  ghostscript-9.10.tar.gz"
    04_cd_gs:
        command: "cd ghostscript-9.10"
    05_configure_gs:
        command: "bash configure"
    06_install_gs:
        command: "make install"
    07_so_gs:
        command: "make so"
    08_reboot:
        command: "reboot"
```

And here goes the elastic beanstalk error log part:

```
[2016-06-21T12:22:52.720Z] INFO  [24703] - [Application update Come on #15@25/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_2__Staging/Command 01_admin_rights] : Starting activity...
[2016-06-21T12:22:52.757Z] INFO  [24703] - [Application update Come on #15@25/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_2__Staging/Command 01_admin_rights] : Completed activity.
[2016-06-21T12:22:52.757Z] INFO  [24703] - [Application update Come on #15@25/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_2__Staging/Command 02_get_gs] : Starting activity...
[2016-06-21T12:22:53.524Z] INFO  [24703] - [Application update Come on #15@25/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_2__Staging/Command 02_get_gs] : Completed activity. Result:
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100 33.6M  100 33.6M    0     0  49.2M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 49.2M

[2016-06-21T12:22:53.524Z] INFO  [24703] - [Application update Come on #15@25/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_2__Staging/Command 03_extract_gs] : Starting activity...
[2016-06-21T12:22:55.066Z] INFO  [24703] - [Application update Come on #15@25/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_2__Staging/Command 03_extract_gs] : Completed activity.
[2016-06-21T12:22:55.066Z] INFO  [24703] - [Application update Come on #15@25/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_2__Staging/Command 04_cd_gs] : Starting activity...
[2016-06-21T12:22:55.069Z] INFO  [24703] - [Application update Come on #15@25/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_2__Staging/Command 04_cd_gs] : Completed activity.
[2016-06-21T12:22:55.070Z] INFO  [24703] - [Application update Come on #15@25/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_2__Staging/Command 05_configure_gs] : Starting activity...
[2016-06-21T12:22:55.073Z] INFO  [24703] - [Application update Come on #15@25/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_2__Staging/Command 05_configure_gs] : Activity execution failed, because: bash: configure: No such file or directory
 (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
[2016-06-21T12:22:55.073Z] INFO  [24703] - [Application update Come on #15@25/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_2__Staging/Command 05_configure_gs] : Activity failed.
```

I understand that the command 5 is failing because the file doesn't exist. However when I'm doing the steps manually via SSH the file exists and all commands can be executed in this order.

What do I miss?

EDIT:
I played around with the configure argument and tried:

/bin/bash: ./configure

./configure

bash ./configure

All arguments fail with the same error "No such file or directory."
If I connect via SSH and enter one of the configure commands then it works without any issues.

Anybody knows whats going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be because separate commands don't keep the environment or the current directory consistent between them. One of your commands is `cd`, but I don't think the changed directory persists to the next command. Try combining all commands into one, like this:

```
command: |
  cd directory
  ./configure
```

Also, ebextensions run as root, so you may not need the `sudo su` in the beginning.